# Set TabItem headers on different place

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do TabControl like this

[TabControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKwyt.png)

I want to make the options tab, which is located on the bottom left
but dont know how to change the position of the title for Tab2

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab1" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab1 content" />
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab2" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab2 content" />
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: can you post the current state of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to insert a invisible dummy `TabItem` whose height matches the gap before the last `TabItem`.

```xml
<TabItem Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

You can set its height in designer or at run time by the following method.

```
void SetDummyTabItemHeight(TabItem dummyItem)
{
    var tabPanel = (TabPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dummyItem);

    var otherItemsActualHeight = tabPanel.Children
        .Cast<TabItem>()
        .Where(x => x != dummyItem)
        .Sum(x => x.ActualHeight);

    dummyItem.Height = tabPanel.ActualHeight - otherItemsActualHeight;
}
```

Comment: I understand there is no more elegant way?

Comment: I don't know any other simple solution but you can dig into `TabItem` and `TabPanel` source code in Reference Source.

Comment: Thank you so much
i will use this method